# Windows driver installer which installs java native libraries as well

Tags: java, java-native-interface, windows-installer, driver

Basically I'm looking to create a silent windows installer which will install Windows drivers and a Java native library (RXTX) which our program use to communicate with the device.

We have drivers for Windows XP, Vista and 7 32bits and 64bits to install. As for the Java native lib, it's only a single file but we have to read the registry first to get the JavaHome path in order to copy the dll at the right place (JavaHome/bin).

I heard about the DIFx framework but I don't know if it can browse the registry and extract a file path from the key. In the other hand, I might be able to just do this with a small C# software but I'm afraid I'll have problems installing the drivers which (AFAIK) needs to be installed in a driver store in Windows vista and 7 but not in windows XP.

Any idea what I could use in order to do this?

Comment: Do your customers really want you to put this in their java home for them?  I would be really offended if your installer started splatting stuff in my java home.

Comment: Well our java application is an applet so I don't think we can put the native lib anywhere else. Can we?

Comment: Gotcha - thanks for the clarification.  When I read your question, I had the impression that you were delivering just an API to customers that was native libs with a JNI wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a small Visual C++ program which browse the registry using RegGetValue() to find the JavaHome and copy the Java native library in there. As for the driver installation, I used DifxAPI (DriverPackagePreinstall()).

For now I only tested this solution on Windows 7 64-bit but so far it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Most setup authoring tools offer driver support, and can even install Java libraries. Here is a list that can get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

After you decide on a tool, try to use it for your package. If you encounter problems you can then ask more specific questions.